# A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found

Tags: iphone, provisioning

I just cracked open an older project to apply a bug fix.

After 2 minutes of fixing the, bug I go to build it to my device, and I get this error "A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found."

In mad trouble shooting, I completely made new distribution and developer certificates, as well as a new certificate for the app.

Still, same error.

Can anyone provide a list of things to check? Ways I can troubleshoot this further?

Cheers. 
PS. I hate provisioning.

EDIT: I'm using the team provisioning profile... is that a problem?  I'm just trying to debug to a device.. it shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Ok, so I solved this, somehow in trying to build for the app store I changed the build config for the "run" scheme from debug to release.. and naturally release was using a distribution cert.. which wasn't (and can't be) installed on my device.

I hate xcode 4. (this aspect of it :P)

What is a scheme anyway? :S

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution. I've tried all the suggestions, including yours, and I'm still getting this error (on an iPod Touch running 3.1.3).

Comment: Got it working
I saw this problem because I had obtained a new Mac, and was still using my old Computer's certificate. I had created a new certificate for the new Mac, but had both certificates in my keychain.In the Organizer, the profile warned that "XCode could not find a valid private-key/certificate pair for this profile in your keychain" even though the old certificate existed in my Keychain.
The solution was to delete the old certificate from my Keychain and delete/revoke of all the profiles which used this old certificate. Then create a new profile with the new certificate and use this.

Comment: I hate all aspects of Xcode 4. Xcode 3 is far superior in 99% of times.

Answer (score 6):

I have a solution as well.  This happened to me last night with the exact same error.  I had a program that was previously compiling and now that I am adding an update to my app, the same error was displayed.  The problem is that I forgot to change my provisioning profile back to Developer. (You set it to Distribution when uploading your app to the App Store).

Here are the settings for Xcode 4.6.

In your app click Targets -> YourAppName -> Code Signing Identy.

Change iPhone Distribution to iPhone Developer.

Your app will now compile.

Answer (score 2):

1- TARGETS -> click the app-> Build Setting-> Code Signing :
       Make sure that both "Debug" and "Any iOS SDK" are set to "iPhone                                   Development"

2- Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme:
       Make sure Build Configuration is set to Debug.

Answer (score 2):

After Struggling many hours I found a solution below.

Just open **"File" -> "Project Setting"** or "Workspace Setting"

Select **"Legacy Build System"** from **"Build System"**
then make it **"Done"**.

Now clean and run your app again. It Works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign provision profile at target level as well as Project level. So if you are using Xcode 4 you can see two column. So you need to assign provision profile in both. Also, Make sure

1. you drag and drop your provision profile to iTunes or Xcode.
2. Make sure you added your device id in the new provision profile.

Select provision profile in all the configuration if above not work. Just to give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your device to the provisioning portal and that profile needs to be installed on the device. In Xcode4 you can do all this via organiser once you have added the device id on the site.

Answer (score 0):

For that, you can check it in below way:

1) First confirm that certificate is installed in your mac properly. Both certificate Distribution & Developer should be added properly. And if it is not there, then create new and then again install it.

2) Check profiles Developer, Distribution & AdHoc profile install properly. And these all profiles must be bounds with respective certificates. And if profile was expire then create the new one and again install it.

3) Then set profiles in your project.

I hope these all check will be helpful to you and you will able to test your app in device.

Cheers.

Comment: Check, Check, Check. Still no luck :(

Comment: I hope you have also checked that, your Device UDID number is added in both profiles Developer & AdHoc.

Answer (score 0):

in addition to all the above responses try also deleting entitlements file and re-create it and provide the application identifier accurately.

i dont say the above error is bcoz of entitlements file but might be  a chance.try once,if it works u are happy.

TNQ

Comment: in your xcode on left panel under resources folder you cand find a file named Entitlements.plist

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with getting an app onto an iPad, even though it worked on other iPads and an iPhone. I eventually solved it by adding it manually using the 40 digit device ID via the provisioning portal.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was due to having "valid signing identity error" on my profile. I revoked my certificate, delete my profile, recreated everything and then did the steps from the answer on this post:

[Xcode 4 - "Valid signing identity not found" error on provisioning profiles on a new Macintosh install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6769345/xcode-4-valid-signing-identity-not-found-error-on-provisioning-profiles-on-a)

Answer (score 0):

1) First confirm that certificate is installed in your mac properly.
2) Both certificate Distribution & Developer should be added properly.
3) And if it is not there, then create new and then again install it.
4) Then set profiles in your project.

I hope these all check will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was the problem when I setup my time manually two month earlier on my iPhone. But when I changed to set time automatically, it worked fine.

`Setting` -> `General` -> `Date & Time` -> `set time automatically`

If it does not work, set time automatically of both mac & iPhone, it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I recently just had this problem and my issue was that my main account holder had to re-approve the agreement.

Answer (score -1):

Change settings like on screen.

[image: Change settings like on screen.]