# xcode "A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found"

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, iphone-6

Since upgrading to xcode 6 yesterday i have problems running an app from xcode on one of my devices and i have no idea why.

The message is:

```
A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found
```

I have checked all the solutions from [A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6518727/a-valid-provisioning-profile-for-this-executable-was-not-found) and ["A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found" error when trying to run unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22993092/a-valid-provisioning-profile-for-this-executable-was-not-found-error-when-tryi) but everything is correct.

So i have the right provisioning profile set, it is installed in the list of provisioning profiles on the device (and not expired) and the build configuration is debug.

I have no further ideas now.

EDIT: another device has no problem. So it might be specific to iphone 6.

Comment: update your device too.

Comment: Unfortunately not possible, i need to test on the device with the ios version that is currently installed.

Comment: what is your xcode version and what is your device version....

Comment: it's xcode 6.2, IPhone 6 with 8.1 installed

Answer (score 2):

As your profile is working on one device that means issue is related to your iPhone 6 device.

You can try the following steps :

1) When you create your provision profile, check whether your device is selected for that particular device. If not then select and again download the provision profile and install it.

2) Just see in your phone whether you have any expired provision profiles. If yes then delete all expired provision profile first.

3) Delete your application from your device if it is previously installed.

4) Select proper provision profile in your project and hit run.

Comment: thanks, 1) allready contacted our ios administrator to do so. 2) There aren't any. 3) Well yes, another version with a different identifier, i'll try that 4) Will do after step 3. I will get back if anything helped.

Comment: patience my friend, i was assigned to another task and couldnt verify. But to make it short: it didn't help. I followed everything step by step but still getting this error.

Answer (score -1):

Try following steps:

1. Open Build Settings > Select Code Signing
2. Provisioning Profile > Automatic.

This is work for me. :)